# How to move view from inside a container view to inside another container view?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, nested, coordinates

I've got a main view.
Inside main view are two container views: buttons container and display container.
Inside each of those containers are buttons and display fields, respectively.

So in short, I've got three levels of views: main, sub (containers), and sub-sub (buttons and fields).

When a button is pressed, I want to animate an image of that button from the button area to the display area. That is, I need to move it two levels up, then two levels back down.

Currently, I'm creating a UIImage, identical to the custom button's UIImage, on top of the button. I move it, then destroy it at the end of the animation, so I don't have to alter the actual button (which I want to stay in place so I can re-use it).

Obviously I can get this UIImageView's center/bounds/frame.

However, I'm having trouble determining the coordinates for the destination.  Frame and Center are relative to the superview, but that's just one level up. Seems like there's a lot of math do to in order to add up the correct X and Y offsets to get to the destination.

Is this a job for UIView's convertRect:toView: or convertRect:fromView: ?  I'm having a hard time determining just how to use those, or deciding whether they're actually the right methods to use.

Seems like a common enough problem - moving something from one "nested" view to another "nested" view - but I've searched and can't find the answer.

Comment: convertRect:... are definitely the right methods to use for this.

Answer (score 0):

Those convertRect methods are tough to get the hang of.  Your view contains two sub views subA and subB, and subA contains a button, and you'd like to animate the button moving from subA to subB.  Let's do the animation in the view controller that has the main view....

```
// subA is the receiver.  that's the coordinate system we care about to start
CGRect startFrame = [subA convertRect:myButton.frame toView:self.view];

// this is the frame in terms of subB, where we want the button to land
CGRect endFrameLocal = CGRectMake(10,10,70,30);
// convert it, just like the start frame
CGRect endFrame = [subB convertRect:endFrameLocal toView:self.view]; 

// this places the button in the identical location as a subview of the main view
// changing the button's parent implicitly removes it from subA
myButton.frame = startFrame;
[self.view addSubview:myButton];

// now we can animate in the view controller's view coordinates
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    myButton.frame = endFrame;  // this frame in terms of self.view
} completion^(BOOL finished) {
    myButton.frame = endFrameLocal;  // this frame in terms of subB
    [subB addSubview:myButton];
}];
```

Comment: Almost worked - had to make one change: Since subB is NOT inside a container view, that is, it's a child of the view controller's view (self), so I don't see the need for convertRect'ing the endLocalFrame. Since subB's frame is already in main view's coordinate system, just grab frame from subB and perform animation to that - as in **myButton.frame = subB.frame;}** - Right? This was a big help, it's working well now, thank you.

Comment: That will change the buttons frame to cover subB. I thought subB was a larger region and you wanted the button placed within it.